"password authentication failed" for user after moving the credentials to .env file
I'm just trying to figure out this issue of "port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username" connection to server at "localhost"". The below code works fine in the dev environment but after I host it to Digital ocean it is not working. My setting.py code is
config = environ.Env()
# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT"),
    }
}

and the .env file is like
SECRET_KEY=#$@#$@#$$##$%^%^&%^$#%#$%#$%
DEBUG=True
DB_NAME=polymath_core
DB_USER=dc_user
DB_PASSWORD=#$#$$%#$#%$###$
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432


and the error
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dc_user"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dc_user"

The pg_hba.config

Just cant figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

For your Django app to function in production, you need to set your environment variables in Digital Ocean. Have you done this?

I put them in  to .env file and loading  it.

Not sure how it works for Digital Ocean but From my understanding, your environment variables in .env works for your local environment. In production, you'd usually have to set it up on your host platform. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-django-to-app-platform

Not sure why but same method works for Mysql.

To question add, as text not images: 1) Postgres version. 2) Did you do dump/restore from dev to prod? 3) Can you connect using psql and appropriate arguments?


16 2. No. I use migration in django 3. yes

